# Runtime error: addition of unsigned offset- leetcode

Tags: c++

I was solving a question on leetcode titled Peak Index in a Mountain although I was able to pass the custom test cases but when I submitted it showed runtime error.
Here is the code

```
int peakIndexInMountainArray(vector<int>& arr) {
    int s=0;
    int e=arr.size()-1;
    int m=s+(e-s)/2;
    
    while(s<=e){
        
        if(arr[m-1]<arr[m] && arr[m]>arr[m+1]){
            return m;
            
            
        }
        else if(arr[m]<arr[m+1]){
            s=m+1;
        }
        else{
            e=m-1;
        }
        
        m=s+(e-s)/2;
        
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

The last output executed which showed error - [3,5,3,2,0]

The error statement-

```
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6030000002b0 overflowed to 0x6030000002ac (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
```

I need some help finding the exact error in the code.

Comment: `arr[m] > arr[m + 1]`   Check the result of `m + 1` and you'll find that it's out of bounds. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/bj7qGKdx1)

Comment: Life gets easier if you get familiar with half-open intervals. That they are conventional is not an accident.

Comment: Think about a vector with one element. Then you have s = 0, e = 0, m = 0, and the first thing you do in the loop is `arr[-1]<arr[0] && arr[0]>arr[1]`, where the only valid index is 0. Be more carefful with your bounds.

Answer (score 0):

For the case`s=e` you have `m=s=arr.size()-1` iff you now access `arr[m+1]` you are out of bounds.